# MySql index generated column that holds dynamic data?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am working with mysql geo location queries and its all working fine. however, when i try to return distance in meters (as a generated col) and then order it closest to farthest this eats up time. Close to 14 sec on a 100k data set.

as mentioned distance_in_meters is a generated col and not indexed. 
is there a way to index this generated col even though the data that will go in it is always going to be different? Would indexing this col even help?

Comment: Do you really need to calculate it for all rows?  If you wanted to limit results, to say, within 100 miles. then WHERE ABS(latitude1,latitude2)<3 and ABS(longitude1,longitude2)<3 would limit the number of rows where you had to do the full calculation.

Answer (score 0):

An index, by design, is 'static'.  That is, if nothing changes *inside* the table, the index does not need to change.  Outside changes have no impact on the index.

Your task seems to be "I am at (lat, lng); where are the 10 nearest coffee shops".  The (x,y) is outside data that is needed for computing "nearest" (ie, distance).  You are asking for a dynamic index.  So, "no".

The task can be *helped* by `INDEX(latitude)` (or longitude), but that brings it down from a full-table scan to scanning a significant chunk of the table.  That may be 'good enough' for 100K rows.

If you grow to a lot more rows and/or you become I/O bound (due to small RAM), then you will need my [*blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).